# Tabs do not load the content in their tab-panes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a bootstrap site with  nav-tabs navigation. I cant seem to figured out why my tabs do not load the content in its tab-pane. I can get it to work in a tutorial but on on my project. Any help would be appreciated. I just wanted the tabbed content to appear when i click its link. Currently its staying on the first tab and it doesn't move. thank you!

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#myTab a:first').tab('show')
          })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="cover">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#profile">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#messages">Messages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#settings">Settings</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Your Home tab content here</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Your Profile tab content here</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Your Messages tab content here</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Your Settings tab content here</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cover-image" style="background-image: url(https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1418065460487-3e41a6c84dc5?q=75&amp;fm=jpg&amp;s=127f3a3ccf4356b7f79594e05f6c840e);"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1 class="text-inverse">Heading</h1>
                    <p class="text-inverse">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici eli.</p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Click me</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: See this http://www.bootply.com/FArUNyj3TY in conjunction with madaaah's answer: You're missing `data-toggle:"tab"` on your `<li><a href="#..." data-toggle="tab">...</a></li>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code provided by Boostrap on their Documentation, in your code I can see that there is far less attributes on the structure, probably the lack of one is messing with the functioning.

Data-toggle and role are the more likely ones.

Good luck. ;)

```html
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet is in plain HTML as you didn't include `bootstrap.css`, and has no functionality as you didn't include `bootstrap.js` and `jquery.js`. Please either add those in or create a JSFiddle or Bootply to better demonstrate your working solution. Also, if `data-toggle` is missing it will cause errors, but `role` will not, as it's an accessibility attribute.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to illustrate that there was missing attributes, cause I already had that kind of error and that was the reason, but was short on time. Thanks for the objective explanation on how those attributes work, i'm sure it will be helpful in the future. Wish you all the best.

Comment: Ohh I see. Well in that case, just remove the code snippet altogether. If it has no functionality and you didn't intend it to have any, you probably don't need it at all, so I can remove it for you :) I didn't realize you were just showing the markup, but that makes sense. Cheers

Comment: This is pretty much "here's the documentation, good luck" and not a working solution. As such, I would argue this should be a comment with a link to the documentation (and I have flagged it as such).

Comment: You can keep the code there, but the snippet wasn't doing anything, so I removed that, but @Cᴏʀʏ does have a point, the markup may not be a complete solution to the question, but adding `data-toggle` to the `<a>` tags does fix their missing functionality: http://www.bootply.com/FArUNyj3TY

Comment: Ok, i'm not so active in here, but I read the rules... Just need some practice on how to post stuff... Sorry.

Comment: That's not a problem, you'll get the hang of it eventually.